# Exec stored procedure into dynamic temp table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

To my knowledge; what I want to do is not possible in sql, but it is worth asking you guys.

Lets say I have a stored procedure abc that returns columns Id and Value. This stored procedure is mainly being used by other departments for functional reasons and I will only use it every now and again for data checks.

So using it as part of my stored procedure:

```
DECLARE @tABC TABLE
(
   ID      INT,
   Value   DECIMAL(12,2)
)

INSERT INTO @tABC
   EXEC OtherDb.DataProd.abc
```

Oky so this will work perfectly for now, but what if they change the structure of their stored procedure?

Adding or removing a column from their stored procedure will break my code, so is there a way of making my code more flexible.

My last desperate attempt went something like this:

```
WITH tempTable AS
(
    EXEC OtherDb.DataProd.abc
)
SELECT ID, Value FROM tempTable
```

Which obviously failed miserably.

Comment: That is why you should use table valued functions or table variables instead of stored procedures to return tables. Anyway, OPENROWSET might be a solution for you

Comment: @adrianm Your comment about UDFs actually solved my issue. I cant believe I did not see that before.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Insert results of a Stored Procedure into a Temporary Table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/653714/insert-results-of-a-stored-procedure-into-a-temporary-table)

Comment: No matter how dynamic your code is if they remove columns that you use your code is broken. Do not add unnecessary overhead to your process due to poor change control. I have done a lot of dynamic code, but never for the reason of poor change control

Answer (score 8):

```
SELECT * INTO #TempTable 
FROM OPENROWSET
('SQLNCLI','Server=(local)\SQL2008R2;Trusted_Connection=yes;',
     'EXEC OtherDb.DataProd.abc')

SELECT * FROM #TempTable
```

Comment: Is enabling OPENROWSET not a security risk?

Comment: To a certain extent, yes. But there is no other way of meeting your requirement, AFAIK

Answer (score 6):

Insert into a temp table. I know this works in 2008 and above, not sure about 2005. Your temp table columns must match your Stored Proc columns.

```
create table #mytable (custid int,company varchar(50),contactname varchar(50)
                , phone varchar(50),address1 varchar(50)
                , address2 varchar(50),city varchar(50)
                ,st varchar(2),zip varchar(20))

insert into #mytable (custid,company,contactname,phone,address1,address2,city,st,zip)
exec dbo.sp_Node_CustomerList_wService @segid = 1

select * from #mytable
where custid = 5

drop table #mytable
```

Comment: The question says "Oky so this will work perfectly for now, but what if they change the structure of their stored procedure?" So this is not a good solution.

Comment: I agree with the comment by: 
Adriaan Davel Jul 20 '16 at 9:15
See his comment above.

Answer (score 1):

It is better and easy way to use openrowset

```
SELECT * INTO #tempTable FROM OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI', 'Server=localhost;Trusted_Connection=yes;', 'EXEC OtherDb.DataProd.abc')
```

Comment: Please add some description to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Otherwise have a look over here, there are more options explained there: [Insert results of a stored procedure into a temporary table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/653714/how-to-select-into-temp-table-from-stored-procedure)?