# INSERT INTO variable column count

Tags: sql-server

Unknown number of columns returned from EXEC result.

```
INSERT INTO #FullTempClr ([Id], [Value1],[Value2], ..., [Value11])
EXEC [report].[TestReport] @Id
```

Howerver, sometimes TestReport returns Id and 10 values, sometimes Id and 11 and sometimes Id and 1 value. If only Valu1 is available, we need to put null or 0 into other values. Is it possible on this level to do this or the only way is to modify [report].TestReport?

SQL Server 2008 r2

Comment: you should add that logic into your stored procedure, so that it always returns the same number of columns

Comment: I agree with Lamak this logic should be taken care of in a stored procedure.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exec stored procedure into dynamic temp table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20280111/exec-stored-procedure-into-dynamic-temp-table)

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way for this is to encapsulate all the logic into a stored procedure or you can use something like this:

```
SP_CONFIGURE 'show advanced options',1
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO
SP_CONFIGURE 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries',1
GO
SELECT * INTO #TempTable 
FROM OPENROWSET
('SQLNCLI','Server=YourLocalServer;Trusted_Connection=yes;',
    'EXEC YourStoredProcedure')
GO
SELECT * FROM #TempTable
GO
DROP TABLE #TempTable
```

you can also take a look at this post [Stored Procedure with dynamic result into temp table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35323846/stored-procedure-with-dynamic-result-into-temp-table)